# Join table without any reference

Tags: php, mysql

in the result of sql query, I will check with php which column has record.

example:

```
  if ($column_1) {echo $column_1}
  if ($column_2) {echo $column_2}
  if ($column_3) {echo $column_3}
```

I don't use `else if` there because I need it to continue in checking the record from the sql query.

However with the php code above, I can't union table in order to get another record of column from that table too. First, because the column count doesn't match. Then even though I manipulate the column, it will give me a duplicate row.

What I have been trying so far to achieve this is to use sub query. But before I know the result, it has come with an error.

Well, this is my full code. Have a look, please.

```
$sql = "SELECT      op.reference_no, op.eight_percent, op.ten_percent, 
                    op.date, op.claim, op.orders_history_id, 
                    oh.one_product_price, oh.quantity, 

                    (
                        SELECT      it.type 
                        FROM        infimoney_transfer it
                    ),
                    (
                        SELECT      it.receiveable 
                        FROM        infimoney_transfer it
                    ),
                    (
                        SELECT      oh.id AS ohid 
                        FROM        infimoney_transfer it
                    )

        FROM        order_promotion op

        LEFT JOIN   orders_history oh 
        ON          oh.id = op.orders_history_id

        WHERE       oh.customer_id = $member_id";


        $saldo = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if(!$saldo){ printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error); die(); }

        if ($saldo->num_rows > 0) {
            while($objek = $saldo->fetch_object()) {


                if ($objek->eight_percent) 
                {
                    $sourceCash = $objek->quantity % 10 > 4 ? 1 : 0;
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$objek->reference_no . "</td>
                            <td>Cashback 8%</td>
                            <td>".$objek->date."</td>
                            <td>".$sourceCash * 5 * $objek->one_product_price."</td>
                            <td>".$objek->eight_percent."</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            <td> Not Yet </td>
                         </tr>";
                }
                if ($objek->ten_percent) 
                {
                    $sourceCash = (int)($objek->quantity / 10);
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$objek->reference_no . $objek->orders_history_id."</td>
                            <td>Cashback 10%</td>
                            <td>".$objek->date."</td>
                            <td>".$sourceCash * 10 * $objek->one_product_price."</td>
                            <td>".$objek->ten_percent."</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            <td> Not </td>
                         </tr>";
                }
                if ($objek->claim) 
                {
                    $sourceCash = (int)($objek->quantity / 10);
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$objek->reference_no . $objek->orders_history_id."</td>
                            <td>Claimed</td>
                            <td>".$objek->date."</td>
                            <td>".$objek->claim."</td>
                            <td> - </td>
                            <td>".$objek->claim."</td>
                            <td> Not </td>
                         </tr>";
                }
```

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you give the exact error message?

Comment: Warning: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row in

Answer (score 1):

If you join your tables all in the same select query, it will not give you duplicate rows:

```
$sql = "SELECT  op.reference_no, op.eight_percent, op.ten_percent, 
                op.date, op.claim, op.orders_history_id, 
                oh.id, oh.one_product_price, oh.quantity, 
                it.type, it.receiveable, 
        FROM order_promotion op 
        LEFT JOIN orders_history oh ON oh.id = op.orders_history_id 
        LEFT JOIN infimoney_transfer it ON it.orders_list_id=oh.order_list_id 
        WHERE oh.customer_id = $member_id";
```

Comment: I am sorry. Please read again my question. You are right. But my actual problem is not like that. Please read again.

Comment: The query here should give you all of those columns in each row, which you can then process however you require. If that's not what you want, could you perhaps explain what you expect the result set to look like?